# VueJS select placeholder does not display with v-model not empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, placeholder, v-model

here my code :

```
<b-field style="display:inline-block;width:calc(90% / 4);" label="Par Filiale">
        <b-select placeholder="Choix de la filiale" v-model="searchFiliale">
            <option :value="null" disabled>Sélectionner une filiale</option>
            <option :value="''"></option>
            <option
                v-for="filiale in listServicesPartenairesFiliales.filiales"
                :value="filiale.name"
                :key="filiale.id">
                {{ filiale.name }}
            </option>
        </b-select>
    </b-field>
```

And the datas :

```
data() {
        return {
            searchFiliale: this.$root.getParamUrl('filiale') || '',
        }
    },
```

The problem is that the placeholder of b-select does not display because `searchFiliale` is not empty or null.
Do you have an alternative to keep `searchFiliale` in `v-model` like here but with the good placeholder ?
Thank you !

Comment: Did you tried with: `:placeholder="searchFiliale"`?

Comment: Yes but i want to display the actual placeholder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a temporary solution :

```
<option :value="''" disabled selected>Choisir une filiale</option>
```

It's not a real placeholder but it's the same effect.

If you have another solution I am interested.

Comment: this does show in the options as disabled field but it does not show the initial placeholder.  did you managed to show the placeholder too?